# Pegar vários valores entre tags

Tags: delphi

Eu preciso pegar um valor entre as tags de um texto, então achei aqui no site a função:

```
function ExtractText(aText, OpenTag, CloseTag : String) : String;
```

Funcionou perfeitamente, porém com apenas o primeiro valor encontrado.

Mas se eu tiver mais TAGs iguais, pra adicionar todos valores dentro dessas TAGs iguais em um ListBox, como devo fazer, pois não encontrei em lugar nenhum. Exemplo:

```
<t1>teste1</t1>
<t2>teste2</t2>
<t1>teste3</t1>
<t1>teste4</t1>
<t3>teste5</t3>
```

Se eu pegar as tags t1 e /t1, queria exibir assim no ListBox:

```
teste1
teste3
teste4
```

Comment: Já pensou em fazer isso em loop? Em while por exemplo. Isso poderia ser feito em todo o listbox e retornar somente quando existe a tag por exemplo.

Answer (score 2):

A função abaixo varre um texto, e verifica em um *loop* se o elemento atual contém a *tag*, se tiver, adiciona na StringList. Essas informações são obtidas através da interface [`IHTMLDocument2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
// Incluir em Uses: ActiveX, MSHTML   
Function ParseTag(Const Texto, Tag: string): TStringList;
Var
 Doc, Elementos: OleVariant;
 I: integer;
begin
  Doc := CoHTMLDocument.Create as IHTMLDocument2;
  try      
    Result := TStringList.Create;
    Doc.write(Texto);

    for I := 0 to Doc.body.all.length - 1 do begin
      Elementos := Doc.body.all.item(I);
      if Elementos.tagName = Tag then
        Result.Add(string(Elementos.innerText));
    end;
  finally
    Doc.close;
  end;
end;
```

Para usa-la chame no evento `OnClick()` de um botão:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
ListBox1.Items.AddStrings(ParseTag('HTML aqui', 'H1'));
end;
```